# How can I open a url when click on push notification, when app is closed, sent by Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I receive notifications when the app is closed and when it's open, but when it's closed and I click on the push notification that has a link it only opens the app and doesn't open the browser, and if the app is open and I click on the push notification the browser opens.

How can I open the browser when I click on a push notification that has a URL and when the app is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An FCM with `notification` payload does *not* go through the `onMessageReceived` when your app is not running. It's posted by Google Play Services on your behalf directly to notification shade. Once clicked your main activity is launched and intent extras contain the `data` payload.

You have two options:

1. Continue using `notification` payload and handle the data in your main activity `onCreate`.

That's the activity started by launcher. Use this for information push notifications. If your app is not running it won't be started, which saves battery.

2. Don't use `notification` payload.

Use this for business logic push messages. This will always start your app process and let you handle the message in `onMessageReceived`.

Read more here:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: Thank you! I suppose that the intent comes to the first activity that is load in my case SplashScreen, sorry for the late reply. @Eugen Pechanec

Comment: Yes, you're right about the first activity. I also added explanation for when to use which option so you can choose better.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below payload if you want to open the WEB URL while clicking on the FCM notification when the app is Killed or in the Background.

```
{
    "to": "device-token",
    "priority":"high",
    "data":{
        "body": "there",
        "title": "Hi",
        "LinkUrl": "https://www.google.com"
    }
}
```

Note: I have not used "notification" in the above payload, if you use the below payload while using the notification keyword in your payload it will open the app not the URL,

```
{
        "to": "device-token",
        "priority":"high",
        "notification":{
           
         },
        "data":{
            "body": "there",
            "title": "Hi",
            "LinkUrl": "https://www.google.com"
        }
    }
```

Cheers!